# History of the triangle inequality

Tags: ho.history-overview, reference-request, mg.metric-geometry

I am currently preparing a talk that revolves around the triangle inequality.

Because this inequality is so well-established, I do not want to (in my talk) belabor too much upon the importance it enjoys. For example, I learned some useful views [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/65513/why-the-triangle-inequality). But, these concerns are currently too advanced---for my purposes, I am seeking first some historical background; specifically,

> Approximately when, where, and how did the concept of a *triangle inequality* get formalized, and its importance recognized?

**EDIT**
It seems that the above question is not precise or clear enough. How about the slightly clarified question:

> When was it realized (was it Fréchet's 1906 paper cited in the comments?) that the triangle inequality should be a fundamental axiom for defining distances?

Comment: Is this question identical to the same question with "triangle inequality" replaced by "metric space"? 

Comment: Hi Qiaochu, could you link to that question? (or do you mean that I should augment / alter the title of this question?)

Comment: I'm not really clear on what "gets formalized" means. I suppose the concept itself was known to the ancient Greeks, and the algebraic inequality for Euclidean distance has been written down for centuries. For "gets formalized" to count, do you mean that the concept of real number should have been made rigorous first? And do you mean introduced as a formal *axiom* for concepts of distance? 


Comment: @Suvrit: what I mean is, if I replaced "triangle inequality" with "metric space" in your question, would that still be faithful to your intended meaning? (Like Todd, I'm not sure what it means to formalize the triangle inequality unless you mean writing down the axioms of a metric space. This was done by Frechet in 1906.) 

Comment: Here's the link to Fréchet's original paper:  http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF03018603 see also this thread http://mathoverflow.net/questions/51494/why-the-name-separable-space/51501#51501 for some comments.

Comment: @Todd and Qiaochu: I would love to know of the oldest source of the algebraic inequality being written down. Also, given your comments, I guess what will be useful to narrate to an audience will be the first time when somebody laid down the *axioms* for concepts of distance. The only catch here is that the triangle inequality itself is part of the axioms, which suggests that in some sense, the "fundamentalness" of the triangle inequality was recognized after people had been happily using distances informally for centuries....

Comment: @Theo: thanks for your comment and the links.

Comment: @Suvrit: I confess I still don't understand your question. When you say "the algebraic inequality," do you mean, for example, the triangle inequality in $\mathbb{R}^n$ in terms of the distance formula? 

Comment: Earlier today (http://mathoverflow.net/questions/72356/) I cited a 1938 paper of Schoenberg that centres on spaces equipped with a "distance function" $d$ that is symmetric and satisfies $d(x, x) = 0$, but doesn't necessarily satisfy the triangle inequality.  (Nor does it satisfy the separation axiom that $d(x, y) = 0$ implies $x = y$, but that's much less important.)  Schoenberg knew Fréchet's definition of metric space, and cites it, but it's instructive to note that Schoenberg was content to talk about "distances" that _don't_ satisfy the triangle inequality.

Comment: @Qiaochu: I mean $d(a,b) \le d(a,c)+d(b,c)$ for some distance function $d$ (not necessarily $R^n$)

Comment: @Tom: Wasn't Schoenberg actually talking about cpd kernels, or essentially, squares of distance functions?

Comment: Maybe it helps, if someone could just tell me: when was it realized that to formalize the notion of a distance, we need to have the triangle inequality as an axiom?

Comment: @Tom: could Schoenberg have been contemplating Lorentzian distances as well?  @Suvrit: unfortunately, I'm not crystal clear yet on the question either. The algebraic formula for Euclidean distance was, I suppose, written down by Descartes (I'm looking now at an edition of La Geometrie, published by Hermann: http://books.google.com/books?id=aHBtAAAAMAAJ&dq=%22Geometry%20of%20Ren%C3%A9%20Descartes%22&source=gbs_similarbooks, page 2), and the triangle inequality for Euclidean distance is given as Proposition 20 in Euclid's Elements, which surely Descartes knew. John Stillwell should be asked...

Comment: @Suvrit: I now see your response to Qiaochu, which appeared while I was composing my last comment. 

Comment: @Suvrit: my main point was that he apparently felt fine about using the term "distance function" in the absence of the triangle inequality, which I'm not sure anyone would do now. The values of his distance functions really _are_ to be thought of as distances, not squares of distances (e.g. when he comes to consider embeddability into Euclidean space). @Todd: possibly, though I don't think he mentions it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a discussion of this issue in Dieudonné's *History of Functional Analysis*, p. 115:

> It may seem obvious to us that the results of Hilbert are but one step removed from what we now call the theory of Hilbert space; but if, in fact, the birth of that theory almost immediately followed the publication of Hilbert's papers, it seems to me that it is due to the fact that this publication precisely occurred during the emergence of a new concept in mathematics, the concept of **structure.**
>
> Until the middle of the XIX<sup>th</sup> century, mathematicians had been dealing with **well determined** mathematical "objects": numbers, points, curves, surfaces, volumes, functions, operators. But the fact that algebraic manipulations on different kinds of "objects" had a strikingly similar appearance soon attracted attention (cf. chap.IV, §3), and after 1840 it gradually became clear that the essence of these manipulations did not lie in the **nature** of the objects, but in the **rules** to be followed in handling them, which might be the same for very different types of objects. However, a precise formulation of this idea had to wait for the adoption of the set-theoretic concepts and language; and it is only in 1895 that our definition of a **group**, on an **arbitrary** underlying set, was formulated by Weber [225]. The trend towards the definition of algebraic structure then gained momentum, and around 1920 all fundamental notions of present-day Algebra had been defined.
>
> In Analysis, no similar development had yet occurred in 1900. The extensions of the ideas of limit and continuity which had been formulated always were relative to **special** objects such as curves, surfaces or functions. The possibility of defining such notions in an **arbitrary** set is an idea which undoubtedly was first put forward by Fréchet in 1904 [69], and developed by him in his famous thesis of 1906 [71].

If I may summarize: the idea that one should talk about mathematical objects in terms of the axioms they should satisfy was itself quite new around 1900, and the specific application of this idea to the triangle inequality seems quite likely to have originated with Fréchet for that reason.

Comment: Thanks Qiaochu; The above quotation is spot-on, and the very last sentence of the quote is essentially the attribution that I was searching for.

Answer (score 3):

It was not Frechet, since the statement that "a line is the shortest distance between two points" (which is obviously equivalent to the triangle inequality) is one of Euclid's axioms, and since Euclid is widely viewed as more of a scribe than the discoverer, presumably it goes back further than that.

Comment: Indeed, that is, as you say, obviously equivalent to the triangle inequality for the sense of d(x, y) as meaning "length of straight-line path from x to y".

One might also consider the sense of d(x, y) as meaning "length of shortest path from x to y" (or, more pedantically, "infimum of path lengths"). But then the triangle inequality is tautologous! (Though there may still be a notable first explicit remark upon this tautology...)

Perhaps we need to figure out which "triangle inequality" exactly is of interest to our question-asker Suvrit.

Comment: **"a line is the shortest distance between two points" ... is one of Euclid's axioms** ... it is not!

Comment: It is Book I, Proposition 20.

Comment: @Gerald. I eat my words.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a suggestion, to get the idea across in an informal way---it is what I always tell the students when I introduce the triangle inequality: I tell them that its essential content, and the way it gets used, is that "things close to the same thing are close to each other".

Comment: This ought to be a comment, because it is not an answer to the question. 

Comment: Actually Dick, I am already quoting this statement of yours (I saw it in your response to a previous triangle-ineq. related question)! 

Comment: @suvrit Right,sorry,I missed the indirect reference.